# awk print line2 to a certain place

Tags: awk

awk to print line 2 and put that between 3rd and 4th backslashs on line 1

line 1 and 2 are

```
http://example.com//
test
```

the output required

```
 http://example.com/test/
```

test could be any word
so cant do it by word

i have already tried with this awk line but that puts it to the end of line 1
not where i want it

```
awk 'NR%2{printf "%s ",$0;next;}1' file1 > file2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one (for lulz, mostly) that works with gawk and mawk but fails with for example original-awk:

```
$ awk '{printf (sub(/\/$/,"")?$0:"") (getline?$0:"") "/" ORS; exit}' file
```

Another, that fails if record on `NR==2` has an `&`, abusing the very feature, though:

```
$ awk '{p=$0;sub(/.$/,(getline?$0 "&":""),p);print p;exit}' file
```

Comment: If by original awk you mean old broken awk then you never need to say if a script fails with that because most script would because it's old and broken. If instead you mean with nawk or a POSIX awk then that's noteworthy but I don't see anything that'd cause it to fail with a functioning awk (all the usual getline caveats aside of course).

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$ awk -F/ -v OFS=/ 'NR == 1 { line = $0; next } 
    { s = $0; $0 = line; $(NF - 1) = s; print }' file
```

Save the first line and skip to the next line. Save the second line, reset `$0` to the first line, insert the content of the second line into the penultimate field and print.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR==1{sub(/\/$/,""); s=$0; next} {print s $0 "/"}' file
http://example.com/test/
```

Answer (score 0):

give this awk one-liner a try:

```
kent$  cat f
http://example.com//
test

kent$  awk -v RS="\0" '{sub("/$",$2"/",$1)}$0=$1' f
http://example.com/test/
```

Comment: Neat. It fails if the second line is for example `test&`, though (I was playing around with similar idea). ... and with that input you could remove the `"/"`part. :D

Comment: IMHO you should only use a non-constant condition for printing when you want the print to occur conditionally. By using `{...}$0=$1` instead of `{...;$0=$1}1` you have to think about whether or not there's cases where $0 might evaluate to something that awk would consider a zero number and so would cause the current record to undesirably not get printed. It also gets the next guy reading your code to wonder why you wrote that as they'll assume you're deliberately trying to only produce output under some condition so it obfuscates your code. Investing in the extra 2 characters is worthwhile!

Answer (score 0):

Short GNU **sed** alternative:

```
sed '1{N; s~/*\n\(.*\)~/\1/~;}' file
http://example.com/test/
```